# Not able to read kafka topic using kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

As I am new to Kafka, so I am able to read the records from the file and send that message to Kafka topic through the producer, but not able to consume the same topic through the consumer.

Note: You can read the data from any text file and I have used kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 version

Here is my code :

```
package implementation;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
//import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
//import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class File_to_Kafka extends ProducerConfig{

    Properties configProperties;
    public File_to_Kafka(Properties originalProps) {
        super(originalProps);
        configProperties = originalProps;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String topicName = "temp"+Math.random();

    public String groupId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();           



        public void producerKafka(Properties configProperties) throws IOException
        {


            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/home/nick/Desktop/Database-Kafka-ElasticSearch/src/main/java/resources/properties.xml");

            configProperties.load(fis);
            System.out.println(configProperties);
            org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(configProperties);

            File f1 = new File("/home/niket/Desktop/sample-example.txt");
            FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(f1);
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1));
            String str = br1.readLine();
            //while(br1.readLine()!=null)
            while(str != null)
            {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, str);
                producer.send(rec);
                str = br1.readLine();
            }

            br1.close();
            fis.close();
            fis1.close();
            producer.close();

        }

        public void consumerKafka() throws InterruptedException
        {
            ConsumerThread consumerRunnable = new ConsumerThread(topicName, groupId);
            consumerRunnable.start();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            consumerRunnable.getKafkaConsumer().wakeup();
            System.out.println("Stopping consumer .....");
            consumerRunnable.join();
        }

        private static class ConsumerThread extends Thread{

            private String topicName;
            private String groupId;
            private KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;


            public ConsumerThread(String topicName, String groupId2) {
                super();
                this.topicName = topicName;
                this.groupId = groupId2;
            }

            public void run()
            {
                Properties configProperties = new Properties();
                configProperties.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092");
                configProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                configProperties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                configProperties.put("group.id", groupId);
                configProperties.put("CLIENT_ID_CONFIG", "simple");

                //Figure out where to tart processing messages from
                kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configProperties);
                kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
                int count=0;



                //Start Processing Messages
                try {
                        while(true) {
                            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
                            count = 0;
                            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                            {
                                    System.out.println(record.value());
                                    count++;
                            }
                            kafkaConsumer.commitAsync();
                            if(count==records.count())
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                catch (WakeupException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println("Exception caught : "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                finally {
                    kafkaConsumer.close();
                    System.out.println("After Closing KafkaConsumer");
                }

            }
            public KafkaConsumer<String,String> getKafkaConsumer(){
                 return this.kafkaConsumer;
              }


        }

        public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            BasicConfigurator.configure();
            Properties configProperties = new Properties();
            configProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            configProperties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
            configProperties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            configProperties.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
            File_to_Kafka obj = new File_to_Kafka(configProperties);
            obj.producerKafka(configProperties);
            obj.consumerKafka();

        }

}
```

Now here is the output :

```
0 [main] INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Verifying properties
61 [main] WARN kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property bootstrap.servers is not valid
62 [main] WARN kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property key.serializer is not valid
62 [main] INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property metadata.broker.list is overridden to localhost:9092
62 [main] WARN kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property value.serializer is not valid
{<name>BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG=(bootstrap.servers)</name>, key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer, <value>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer</value>=, <name>KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name>=, metadata.broker.list=localhost:9092, <configuration>=, <?xml=version="1.0"?>, <name>KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name>=, <property>=, <value>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer</value>=, <value>localhost=9092</value>, bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092, <name>VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name>=, <value>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer</value>=, </property>=, value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer, </configuration>=, <name>VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name>=}
86 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - ProducerConfig values: 
    compression.type = none
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    timeout.ms = 30000
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    ssl.key.password = null
    max.block.ms = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    retries = 0
    max.request.size = 1048576
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    linger.ms = 0

93 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
96 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name buffer-exhausted-records
99 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(-1, localhost, 9092)], partitions = [])
116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name connections-closed:client-id-producer-1
116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name connections-created:client-id-producer-1
116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:client-id-producer-1
116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-sent:client-id-producer-1
117 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-received:client-id-producer-1
117 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name select-time:client-id-producer-1
118 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name io-time:client-id-producer-1
122 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name batch-size
123 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name compression-rate
123 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name queue-time
123 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name request-time
124 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
124 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name records-per-request
125 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name record-retries
125 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name errors
125 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name record-size-max
126 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
126 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <value>localhost = 9092</value> was supplied but isn't a known config.
126 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration </configuration> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
126 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <property> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <value>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer</value> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <name>VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <value>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer</value> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <configuration> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <value>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer</value> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <name>KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <name>BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG = (bootstrap.servers)</name> was supplied but isn't a known config.
127 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration </property> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
129 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <name>VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
129 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <name>KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG</name> =  was supplied but isn't a known config.
129 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration metadata.broker.list = localhost:9092 was supplied but isn't a known config.
129 [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - The configuration <?xml = version="1.0"?> was supplied but isn't a known config.
130 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Kafka version : 0.9.0.0
131 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Kafka commitId : fc7243c2af4b2b4a
131 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer  - Kafka producer started
199 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
199 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9092.
254 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
255 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
255 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.latency
255 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Completed connection to node -1
267 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Sending metadata request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=null, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=3,api_version=0,correlation_id=0,client_id=producer-1}, body={topics=[temp0.8655521798253616]}), isInitiatedByNetworkClient, createdTimeMs=1513840470088, sendTimeMs=0) to node -1
502 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {temp0.8655521798253616=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
502 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(0, niket-Lenovo-Y50-70, 9092)], partitions = [])
502 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Adding node 0 to nodes ever seen
599 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initialize connection to node 0 for sending metadata request
599 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initiating connection to node 0 at niket-Lenovo-Y50-70:9092.
599 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-0.bytes-sent
600 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-0.bytes-received
600 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-0.latency
600 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Completed connection to node 0
600 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Sending metadata request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=null, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=3,api_version=0,correlation_id=1,client_id=producer-1}, body={topics=[temp0.8655521798253616]}), isInitiatedByNetworkClient, createdTimeMs=1513840470433, sendTimeMs=0) to node 0
611 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 3 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(0, niket-Lenovo-Y50-70, 9092)], partitions = [Partition(topic = temp0.8655521798253616, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,]])
619 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name topic.temp0.8655521798253616.records-per-batch
619 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name topic.temp0.8655521798253616.bytes
619 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name topic.temp0.8655521798253616.compression-rate
619 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name topic.temp0.8655521798253616.record-retries
619 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name topic.temp0.8655521798253616.record-errors
646 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer  - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
647 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
667 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name connections-closed:client-id-producer-1
667 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name connections-created:client-id-producer-1
667 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name bytes-sent-received:client-id-producer-1
667 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name bytes-received:client-id-producer-1
668 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name bytes-sent:client-id-producer-1
668 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name select-time:client-id-producer-1
668 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name io-time:client-id-producer-1
668 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
668 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
669 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node--1.latency
669 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node-0.bytes-sent
669 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node-0.bytes-received
669 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node-0.latency
669 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
669 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer  - The Kafka producer has closed.
674 [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig  - ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = 2a4549ce-0e9d-4a66-9573-c5b4c47b3b34
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    enable.auto.commit = true
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    fetch.min.bytes = 1024
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    auto.offset.reset = latest

675 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - Starting the Kafka consumer
675 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(-1, localhost, 9092)], partitions = [])
675 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name connections-closed:client-id-consumer-1
675 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name connections-created:client-id-consumer-1
675 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:client-id-consumer-1
675 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-sent:client-id-consumer-1
676 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-received:client-id-consumer-1
676 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name select-time:client-id-consumer-1
676 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name io-time:client-id-consumer-1
683 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name heartbeat-latency
683 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name join-latency
684 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name sync-latency
685 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name commit-latency
688 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-fetched
688 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name records-fetched
688 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name fetch-latency
688 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name records-lag
688 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name fetch-throttle-time
688 [Thread-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig  - The configuration CLIENT_ID_CONFIG = simple was supplied but isn't a known config.
689 [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Kafka version : 0.9.0.0
689 [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Kafka commitId : fc7243c2af4b2b4a
689 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - Kafka consumer created
689 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - Subscribed to topic(s): temp0.8655521798253616
689 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - Issuing group metadata request to broker -1
690 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9092.
691 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
691 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
691 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.latency
691 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Completed connection to node -1
Stopping consumer .....
Exception caught : null
772 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name connections-closed:client-id-consumer-1
772 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name connections-created:client-id-consumer-1
773 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name bytes-sent-received:client-id-consumer-1
773 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name bytes-received:client-id-consumer-1
773 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name bytes-sent:client-id-consumer-1
773 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name select-time:client-id-consumer-1
773 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name io-time:client-id-consumer-1
773 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
774 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
774 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Removed sensor with name node--1.latency
774 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - The Kafka consumer has closed.
After Closing KafkaConsumer
```

Comment: The whole output has been highlighted. Make it easy to understand for people.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem with your main method. 
It looks like your flow is stuck in the producer while loop.

Can you try starting the consumer in separate main class, you should be able to see consumer getting records.

Comment: Still not able to consume the messages from kafka topic.

Comment: Can you add some debug logs in consumer while loop and share the entire log?

Comment: After adding debug logs I have got org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException